# Trigger a function after data is loaded on the view angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

I am new to angular and just trying to get to grips with it. I have a page that shows shop items

```
<div *ngIf="products" class="col-lg-12">  
  <div *ngFor="let prod of products.data" class="col-lg-3 cont" cdkDrag>
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8 productItem">
      <p class="text-center">
        <img src="https://www.classicposters.com/images/nopicture.gif" width="125" height="160" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <i>{{prod.title}}</i>
        <br />
        <i >{{prod.price | currency:"£"}}</i>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div *ngIf="products" class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
     Page {{products.pageOn}} of {{products.totalPages}}
  </div>  
</div>
```

If products array has values then load them up. There will load opacity 0 and then will load in one after the other. I need to trigger the function for when the content has finished loading before triggering the even.

I have ngOnInit() within my .ts - this creates a subscribe for the data return and puts it in the products array (used in the view) - the data source as a 2 second sleep on it to represent slow load times.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.data.getProducts(1).subscribe(prods => {
      this.products = prods;
    });
    console.log('on init: ' + Date().toString());
  }
```

I tried hooking in the call in the subscriber but it did not work and I then saw about life cycle hooks. I tried AfterViewInit and AfterContentInit but had no joy with either.

How would I go about listening for the page (with data) to finish loading before triggering the function?

Are there any resource to use for helping my find this sort of thing out?

Thanks
Mark

EDIT:
I changed it to use the [hidden] style and then I am able use AfterViewInit to fire the animation cycle. However, I get an error and it is trying to use the products.data when it is not initialised. It seems the *ngIf enables the AfterViewInit to trigger to soon

```
<div [hidden]="!products" class="col-lg-12">  
      <div *ngFor="let prod of products.data" class="col-lg-3 cont">
```

Comment: Just to clarify - you need to know when rendering has been completed?

Comment: That is correct @FrankModica

Comment: Did you try with ngAfterViewChecked()? Angular doc: `Respond after Angular checks the component's views and child views.`

Comment: I have not tried that. However, I was using ngIf="products" so the div would not be there if products did not have a value. I changed that to [hidden]="!products" and then added AfterViewInit life cycle back in and then trigger the loading of the resource then and it worked.

Comment: however i do get errorss show in the console (i imagine whilst products is null and has not loaded could ngAfterViewChecked correct that?)

Comment: What kind of errors do you get?

Comment: Why do you trigger the data loading in ngAfterViewInit? I think ngOnInit() is the good place for that, but I may be wrong, depending on what you want to do

Comment: the data loading is done in OnInit. the data is loaded invisible. and then once the page is rendered (with hidden elements) i want to trigger an "animation" so each item loads one after the other

Comment: Ok, so you want to keep the view hidden until you get your producst array. And then start the animation, is that right?

Comment: yeah that is correct. See the edit about in a minute as to what I changed and what i am experiencing now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187196/discussion-between-jo-va-and-markblue777).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-animate-ngfor) with angular animations:

Here is [some doc](https://angular.io/api/animations/stagger) about the animation (pointed to by @markblue777).

A container element wraps a list of items stamped out by an ngFor. The container element contains an animation trigger `[@listAnimation]` that is be set to query for each of the inner items.

The items are added in sequence with a delay and the opacity fade-in animation runs.

```html
<div *ngIf="products" class="col-lg-12" [@listAnimation]="items.length">  
  <div *ngFor="let prod of items" class="col-lg-3 cont" cdkDrag>
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8 productItem">
      <p class="text-center">
        <img src="https://www.classicposters.com/images/nopicture.gif" width="125" height="160" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <i>{{prod.title}}</i>
        <br />
        <i >{{prod.price | currency:"£"}}</i>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div *ngIf="products" class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
     Page {{products.pageOn}} of {{products.totalPages}}
  </div>  
</div>
```

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
  trigger,
  style,
  query,
  stagger,
  animate,
  transition,
} from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  animations: [
  trigger('listAnimation', [
    transition('* => *', [
      query(':enter', [
        style({ opacity: 0 }),
        stagger(100, [
          animate('0.5s', style({ opacity: 1 }))
        ])
      ], { optional: true })
    ])
  ])
  ],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  products = { pageOn: 0, totalPages: 5, data: null };
  items = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.apiCall().then(products => {
      this.products = products;
      // We then animate the entry of each item separately
      products.data.forEach((product, idx) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.items.push(product);
        }, 500 * (idx + 1)); // Each item is inserted 500ms after the last one.
      });
    });
  }

  // Simulate the API call
  apiCall(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve({ pageOn: 0, totalPages: 10, data: [
          { title: 'cheese', price: 1 },
          { title: 'chothes', price: 2 },
          { title: 'Food', price: 3 },
        ]});
      }, 2000); // with a delay of 2000ms
    })
  }
}
```

You will have to add the `BrowserAnimationsModule` for this to work:

```ts
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```

Comment: From what I remember the ngAfterViewChecked will be called multiple times.
I think that the best way(none angular way) is to use document on ready.

Comment: That worked a treat, thanks @jo_va. just a reminder to do npm install @angular/animations (thanks for pointing that out over chat)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of your problem is that you want a function to run when the page is done painting.

Try injecting the document and turning it into an observable. I haven't played with all the possibilities but this happens when ngoninit is done. Another solution is putting it into a promise block.

```
private documentDone: Observable<any>
constructor(
@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any){}

ngOnInit(): void {
this.documentDone = fromEvent(this.document, 'readystatechange');
this.documentDone.subscribe(state => console.log('im done');
}
```

Comment: this fires before the content is rendered unfortunately